# Eclipse - trouble with Import

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-cayenne

I have project that I am trying to debug, and I am sure its using Cayenne 3.2, I have downloaded the cayenne 3.2 source, now if I try to import the cayenne source as a project after selecting Import -> File System -> and then select the root Cayenne directory or one of the sub directories that has the source, I get 'Source is in the hierarchy of the destination.' and Eclipse does not allows me to import the source. If I do not import it, and when the exception is raised, I click Edit Source Lookup to attach the source, I select the cayenne root directory or one of the sub directories, it does not works. if I select a Jar or zip file, the code is displayed for 1 sec and disappears again !

Would anyone know the fix ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no Cayenne 3.2 yet, so you are probably referring to version 3.1?

To be able to debug Cayenne code called from your code from within your project, you don't need to import Cayenne sources into Eclipse. Instead you need to map your dependency jars to sources located elsewhere. If you are using Maven (and m2eclipse plugin), Maven should be able to do that automatically. If not, you can still download the right sources from the Maven repo to simplify your task. E.g. if you are on 3.1M3 (confirm your version first of course) , go here:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.cayenne|cayenne-server|3.1M3|jar

download cayenne-server-3.1M3-sources.jar and save it locally. Then in Eclipse find cayenne-server-3.1.jar (somewhere in your library dependencies, depending on how your project is setup), right-click on it, select "Properties > Java Source Attachment > External File" and then select the sources file that you just downloaded.